# Binding Universal Image Loader to Xamarin solution

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, universal-image-loader

I' ve been trying to use Universal Image Loader by Nostra13 in Xamarin.Android project.
In My solution I created new JavaBinding Project according to Xamarin docs. I'm In Visual Studio 2013

I 've added theese lines to Metadata.xml according to [this advice](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/1156/adding-android-universal-image-loader-library),

```
<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.imageaware']/class[@name='ImageViewAware']/method[@name='getWrappedView']" name="managedReturn">Android.Views.View</attr>
<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.nostra13.universalimageloader.cache.memory.impl']/class[@name='FIFOLimitedMemoryCache']/method[@name='removeNext']" name="managedReturn">Java.Lang.Object</attr>
<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.nostra13.universalimageloader.cache.memory.impl']/class[@name='LargestLimitedMemoryCache']/method[@name='removeNext']" name="managedReturn">Java.Lang.Object</attr>
<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.nostra13.universalimageloader.cache.memory.impl']/class[@name='LRULimitedMemoryCache']/method[@name='removeNext']" name="managedReturn">Java.Lang.Object</attr>
<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.nostra13.universalimageloader.cache.memory.impl']/class[@name='UsingFreqLimitedMemoryCache']/method[@name='removeNext']" name="managedReturn">Java.Lang.Object</attr>
<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.imageaware']/class[@name='ImageViewAware']/method[@name='getWrappedView']" name="managedReturn">Android.Views.View</attr>

<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.nostra13.universalimageloader.cache.memory.impl']/class[@name='LRULimitedMemoryCache']/method[@name='removeNext']" name="managedReturn">Java.Lang.Object</attr>
```

I also created and filled in the Fixes.cs file.
Project alone can be built, but when I'm referencing the project from AndroidProject. The whole solution is impossible to build, And I'm geting the errors:

```
 Error  95   package com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.assist does not exist
    com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.assist.ImageLoadingListener
C:\work\dos\src\MyProject.Android\obj\Debug\android\src\mono\com\nostra13\universalimageloader\core\assist\ImageLoadingListenerImplementor.java

 Error  96   package com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.assist does not exist
public void onLoadingFailed (java.lang.String p0, android.view.View p1, com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.assist.FailReason p2)
C:\work\dos\src\DOS.Android\obj\Debug\android\src\mono\com\nostra13\universalimageloader\core\assist\ImageLoadingListenerImplementor.java

 Error  97   package com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.assist does not exist
private native void n_onLoadingFailed (java.lang.String p0, android.view.View p1, com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.assist.FailReason p2);
C:\work\dos\src\MyProject\obj\Debug\android\src\mono\com\nostra13\universalimageloader\core\assist\ImageLoadingListenerImplementor.java

 Error  98   package com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.assist does not exist
    com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.assist.ImageLoadingProgressListener
C:\work\dos\src\MyProject.Android\obj\Debug\android\src\mono\com\nostra13\universalimageloader\core\assist\ImageLoadingProgressListenerImplementor.java

 Error  99   package com.nostra13.universalimageloader.utils.IoUtils does not exist
    com.nostra13.universalimageloader.utils.IoUtils.CopyListener
C:\work\dos\src\MyProject.Android\obj\Debug\android\src\mono\com\nostra13\universalimageloader\utils\IoUtils_CopyListenerImplementor.java
```

I' ve been trying version 1.8.4, 1.8.5, and actual 1.9.1 And it is always the same.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I think you can look at 
https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/universalimageloader
I'm not sure both the library are same or not, but this Xamarin Component will help you. It has lots of configurations too.